# Constructing objects via reflection using object's class

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Assuming code like below:

```
public interface Component<T>
{
}
public class ConcreteComponent<T> implements Component<T>
{
}
```

How would you solve such compilation problem:

```
@Override
public Class<? extends Component<?>> getComponentClass() {
    // Does not compile!
    return ConcreteComponent.class;
}
```

Basically, as you can see I'd like to able to construct object via reflection using component's class. Ommiting the details, method's declaration might look like this:

```
public <T extends Component<?>> void createComponent(Class<? extends T> clazz)
{
}
```

And finally:

```
ConcreteComponent<Integer> cmp = createComponent(getComponentClass());
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not very clear what you want, something that works like `ConcreteComponent.class.newInstance()`?

Comment: To be clear, you cannot get a parametrized generic class at runtime because of type erasure; you will only ever get a non-generic version of the class (but it makes no difference).

Comment: @Viruzzo As far as reflection part is concerned, I'd like to get a constructor matching given class, parameters and then call `constructor.newInstance(args)`. But as stated above, I'm trying to declare method which returns this concrete `.class`.

Comment: All this sounds far more easily obtained with a factory pattern, can you explain what is your broader goal here? Is there a reason for this specific solution?

Answer (score 0):

This compiles:

```
public Class<? extends Component> getComponent() {
    // Compiles!
    return ConcreteComponent.class;
}
```

Comment: It does, but that's not really what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Return (Class>) ConcreteComponent.class;

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the below code.
The return type you have mentioned should match the value you have returned so you need to cast it to the return type.

```
public class ConcreteComponent<T> implements Component<T> {
    public Class<? extends Component<?>> getComponent() {     // Does not compile!     
        return (Class<? extends Component<?>>) ConcreteComponent.class;
    } 
}
```

OR

```
public class ConcreteComponent<T> implements Component<T> {
    public Class<? extends Component<?>> getComponent() {     
        return (Class<? extends Component<?>>) this.getClass();
    } 
}
```